# Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer - Error loading property

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Trying to use Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer (version 1.4.2) to access storage accounts in Azure Government. I can connect to the subscription and enumerate the storage accounts but when I click on a storage account, it won't enumerate the containers in the storage account and many of the properties of the storage account show as "Error loading property". I have tried two different Azure Government subscriptions and accessing them from two different computers.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution to your problem but you may want to create an issue here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues.

Storage Explorer team is actively engaged on the issues there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, opened ticket